# Playwright not opening browser on subprocess

Tags: python, linux, playwright, ulimit, setrlimit

I'm trying to use playwright python and restrict its memory using a subprocess using the following code:

```py
# scrapper.py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch()
```

```py
# main.py

import resource
import subprocess

MAX_VIRTUAL_MEMORY = 16 * (1024 ** 3) # in GB

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        def limit_virtual_memory():
            resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (MAX_VIRTUAL_MEMORY, MAX_VIRTUAL_MEMORY))

        p = subprocess.Popen(
            ['python', './src/scrapper.py'],
            preexec_fn=limit_virtual_memory
        )
        p.communicate()
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

The file `main.py` is executed and throws the following error:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/scrapper.py", line 5, in <module>
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
  File "/home/italo/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/livequote-7aGxAPUF-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/sync_api/_generated.py", line 11538, in launch
    self._sync(
  File "/home/italo/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/livequote-7aGxAPUF-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_sync_base.py", line 88, in _sync
    return task.result()
  File "/home/italo/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/livequote-7aGxAPUF-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_browser_type.py", line 90, in launch
    Browser, from_channel(await self._channel.send("launch", params))
  File "/home/italo/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/livequote-7aGxAPUF-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 39, in send
    return await self.inner_send(method, params, False)
  File "/home/italo/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/livequote-7aGxAPUF-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 63, in inner_send
    result = next(iter(done)).result()
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Browser closed.
==================== Browser output: ====================
<launching> /home/italo/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1005/chrome-linux/chrome --disable-field-trial-config --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,GlobalMediaControls,DestroyProfileOnBrowserClose,MediaRouter,DialMediaRouteProvider,AcceptCHFrame,AutoExpandDetailsElement,CertificateTransparencyComponentUpdater,AvoidUnnecessaryBeforeUnloadCheckSync --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-sync --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --no-service-autorun --export-tagged-pdf --headless --hide-scrollbars --mute-audio --blink-settings=primaryHoverType=2,availableHoverTypes=2,primaryPointerType=4,availablePointerTypes=4 --no-sandbox --user-data-dir=/tmp/playwright_chromiumdev_profile-EaCjsb --remote-debugging-pipe --no-startup-window
<launched> pid=9267
[pid=9267][err] ../../base/allocator/partition_allocator/partition_address_space.cc(63) Check failed: false
=========================== logs ===========================
<launching> /home/italo/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1005/chrome-linux/chrome --disable-field-trial-config --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,GlobalMediaControls,DestroyProfileOnBrowserClose,MediaRouter,DialMediaRouteProvider,AcceptCHFrame,AutoExpandDetailsElement,CertificateTransparencyComponentUpdater,AvoidUnnecessaryBeforeUnloadCheckSync --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-sync --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --no-service-autorun --export-tagged-pdf --headless --hide-scrollbars --mute-audio --blink-settings=primaryHoverType=2,availableHoverTypes=2,primaryPointerType=4,availablePointerTypes=4 --no-sandbox --user-data-dir=/tmp/playwright_chromiumdev_profile-EaCjsb --remote-debugging-pipe --no-startup-window
<launched> pid=9267
[pid=9267][err] ../../base/allocator/partition_allocator/partition_address_space.cc(63) Check failed: false
```

The weird part is that my computer contains 16GB of RAM and even setting this a hard/soft limit I couldn't make it work, but if I put a crazy value on `MAX_VIRTUAL_MEMORY` like 64GB this error is not thrown.